# @font-face not working on mirrored site

Tags: wordpress, fonts, font-face, embedded-fonts, font-embedding

I have a wordpress installed site at http://lifebridgecypress.org, and then I also have http://lifebridgecypress.com, which mirrors the .org site.  As you can see, the .com site's @font-face rules are not working.

**Does anyone know a way to get this to work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect .com to .org, something along these lines in a `.htaccess` should do the trick. Requires `mod_rewrite` (which appears to be enabled on your sites).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^(www\.)?lifebridgecypress\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://lifebridgecypress.org/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The two sites look identical to me in Safari5/Mac.

Comment: Incidentally, why not just redirect users to the .org instead of mirroring (and potentially taking a SEO hit for doing so)?

Comment: would I do that through .htaccess?  If so, do you happen to know the code?  I'm sure I'd probably mess it up...

Comment: I'm looking at the sites through the latest version of Firefox on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Simply domain forward lifebridgecypress.com to lifebridgecypress.org at your domain registrar (looks like Dreamhost) so you only have one site to host and administer. And then you don't get down ranked by Google for duplicate content, either.